# How to wrap all but first element with div

Tags: javascript

I need to wrap all elements but the first in a separate div so I can display them with flex

so this:

```
<article>
    <div>image</div>
    <div>title</div>
    <div>byline</div>
    <div>read-more</div>
</article>
```

to this:

```
<article>
    <div>image</div>
    <div>
        <div>title</div>
        <div>byline</div>
        <div>read-more</div>
    </div>
</article>
```

So far I've managed to insert a wrapper div at the start of the article with this:

```
  const postImage = document.querySelector('.w-blog-grid > a > article > div');
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  postImage.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, postImage);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just change the HTML? If not maybe [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) can help

Comment: Due to the constraints of the CMS i'm working with, I can't change the HTML nor use grid 

Comment: Wait why can you use flex but not grid?

Comment: I've been told repeatedly not to use it as it's not supported. But I just looked it up and it seems I've been lied to! Soylent green is people!

Comment: @JakePowell sorry for the late answer but i was in classes.. check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function putInLine(element,numChildrenToSkip){
  if(!numChildrenToSkip){numChildrenToSkip=0}
  //numChildrenToSkip is the number of divs you DON'T want inline
  var el=element.childNodes
  var article=Object.keys(el)
  .filter(a=>el[a].tagName=='DIV').map(a=>el[a])
  //article is an array of divs in element
  article.splice(0,numChildrenToSkip)
  var newDiv=document.createElement('div')
  article.forEach(a=>{
    element.removeChild(a)
    newDiv.appendChild(a)
  })
  //article was used to place desired elements in a div of its own
  element.appendChild(newDiv)
  //newDiv nested in element
}

//implementation of function below
putInLine(document.getElementById('article'),1)

//proof that it works
console.log(document.getElementById('article').children)
```

```html
<article id="article">
    <div>image</div>
    <div>title</div>
    <div>byline</div>
    <div>read-more</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Going with this one as it solved the problem of selecting only one layer of child nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
const article = document.querySelectorAll('article')[0];
const divs = [...article.querySelectorAll('> div')];
const postImage = divs.shift();
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');

article.innerHTML = '';
divs.forEach(div => wrapper.appendChild(div));
article.appendChild(postImage);
article.appendChild(wrapper);
```

Comment: This does work actually, however there are further divs inside the children that are now being spread into the divs array, is there a way to only target one level of div? (if that makes sense)

so ideally just target: 

`
article > div
`

and not 

`
article > div > div
`

 also

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('article')[0]`, if you only need the first element then you can use `document.querySelector()`, saves you from traversing the rest of the DOM tree for the other matching elements